# Windows 7 LAN Unidentified Network

Tags: windows-7, lan

I've got a home network with several computers connected through a hub and another running OpenBSD as the gateway/firewall.  I recently tried to connect a Windows 7 computer to the network, but it says "Unidentified Network" and gives me "no route to host" when I try to ping anything else on the LAN.  I've got the Windows 7 box's IPV4 address set to 192.168.1.18 and the gateway set to 192.168.1.1. I'm not using DHCP and there are no local DHCP servers on the network.

Answer (score 0):

You need to download, compile, and run the LLTD responder daemon.  I've never done so on OpenBSD, but have done so successfully on Linux.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/hardware/gg463094.  You might also look into disabling LLTD on all Windows Vista/7 computers but I'm not sure if that will affect Windows "network identification".

Comment: Sorry I wasn't clear at all. I'm not so much concerned that it's coming up as an "Unidentified Network" as the fact that I can't connect at all.  It gives me a "no route to host" response when I try to ping the gateway.

Answer (score 0):

Well, `route print` pls, from Win7 box and check default route

It seems as some misconfiguration of IPv4-interface (thin netmask, wrong default GW) for me (if other hosts are interpingable)